# To prove the independency of two random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ are of identical independent distribution, with the same PDF $f(x) = e^{-x},  \space x>0$. Now, we have $$Y_1=\min(X_1, X_2)$$ $$Y_2=\max(X_1, X_2)$$  $$Y_3=Y_2 - Y_1$$
The problem is to determine if $Y_1$ and $Y_3$ are independent, and prove why.
Unfortunately, I have no idea how to prove it. I only have the notion of $f(X_1X_2)=f(X_1)f(X_2)$ for $X_1$ and $X_2$ independent. Please help me.

Comment: Have you studied distribution of a function of two random variable?

Comment: Yes I have. However, I don't know how to apply it in this problem.

Comment: $Y_1=g(X_1,X_2)$, $Y_3=h(X_1,X_2)$. You can compute joint density of $Y_1$ and $Y_3$ in terms of joint density of $X_1$ and $X_2$, which is given. Once you have that use the criterion of independence that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to show independence is to compute the joint [complementary cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Complementary_cumulative_distribution_function_.28tail_distribution.29) and that it factors:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
    \Pr(Y_1 > y_1, Y_3 > y_3) &=& \Pr(\min(X_1,X_2) > y_1, \max(X_1,X_2) > y_3 + \min(X_1,X_2))  \\ &=& \Pr(X_1>y_1, X_2 > y_3+X_1 , X_2>X_1) + \\ && \Pr(X_2>y_1, X_1 > y_3+X_2, X_1\geqslant X_2)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where disjointness of events $\{X_2 > X_1\}$ and $\{X_1 \geqslant X_2\}$ was used in the last step.
Assuming $y_3 > 0$ and $y_1>0$, $$\begin{eqnarray} \Pr(X_1>y_1, X_2 > y_3+X_1, X_2>X_1) &=& \Pr(X_1>y_1, X_2 > y_3+X_1) \\  &=& \int_{y_1}^\infty \mathrm{d}x_1 \exp(-x_1) \int_{y_3+x_1}^\infty \exp(-x_2) \mathrm{d}x_2 \\ &=& \int_{y_1}^\infty \mathrm{d}x_1 \exp(-2 x_1 - y_3) \\ &=& \frac{1}{2} \exp(-y_3-2y_1)  \end{eqnarray}
$$
By symmetry $\Pr(X_2>y_1, X_1 > y_3+X_2, X_1\geqslant X_2)$ has the same value. Hence
$$
   \Pr(Y_1 > y_1, Y_3 > y_3) = \exp(-y_3) \cdot \exp(-2y_1)
$$
and the independence follows.

Comment: You might want to omit the conditioning/deconditioning steps, which are unnecessary and make you write wrong intermediate formulas.

Comment: @Did Thank you for pointing out my blunders. I have corrected them now.